# how to print whole content of DIV having horizental and vertical scroll bar using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have a div which contain horizontal and vertical scroller and whenever trying to print the dive using window.print() command method, it only print the visible portion of div .
here are the code which i have tried.

```
<style>
@media print {
 body * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 .printableDiv * {   
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;//  overflow: scroll; or overflow: auto;
}
```

when i use overflow attribute the content will not get print correctly and only top portion of div will get stretch and get print

```
<style>
@media print {
 body * {
  display: none;
}
 .printableDiv * {   
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;//  overflow: scroll; or overflow: auto;
}
```

nothing get print

```
<style>
@media print {
 body * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 .printableDiv * {   
  visibility: visible;
}
```

will print the visible portion of div but even after hiding the rest of element it wont cover the whole page (rest of element are not getting collapse) so i thought of reposition it using below code but that also did not worked.

```
  <style>
@media print {
 body * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 .printableDiv * {   
  visibility: visible;
}
.printableDiv * {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

}

please let me know a solution how to print the content behind the scroller.
**also want to mention this Div is getting populated during the runtime and does not contain static value.**

Comment: you can try this `@media print {
      body, html, #wrapper {
          width: 100%;
      }
}`

Answer (score 2):

`visibility: none` only stops an element being displayed/printed, but isn't removed from the rendering flow, so that it still occupies the same space.

`display: block` on the other hand, does remove the element from the flow, as if it was never there, but it can't be "uninherited": An element inside one with `diplay: none` can't be made visible again with any means.

The best solution, would be to explictly use `display: none` on all elements other than `printableDiv` (and its parents). Also you should remove/reset all positioning style on `printableDiv` (and its parents).

This will strongly depend on the structure of your HTML and how you originally positioned `printableDiv` (and its parents). Example:

```html
<div id="head">...</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="something">
  <div class="printableDiv">...</div>
  <div id="something_else">
</div>
```

```css
@media print {
  #head, #something, #something_else {
    display: none;
  }
  #content, .printableDiv {
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but first of all it wont give me the solution to print all the content of dive specially those which are not visible and need to scroll to get visible and 2nd thing the page is a really complex page and searching all div is difficult and time taking, there must be a workaround for this process as i need to make 200 div to display none....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, especially the first part about scrolling. In case of a complex page, I don't think there is a better solution, other than simplify the page, or use another approach, such as generating a print version of the page server-side.

Comment: can you explain a bit what is printable version of the server side??
sorry if my question sound very elementary, I am new to javascript and UI related stuff.
I mean to say if make some other page also, the whole content wont be fit in display and window.print() seems to print only visible portion of the page

Comment: YOur problem has very little to do with JavaScript (unless there is a script that is messing with the display of the page a lot). Maybe you have some JavaScript that replaces the normal scrolling of the browser, which would make this very difficult without seeing the page. Regarding generating a print version server-side: This depends on what you use on the server-side for page generation. Is it a CMS or some custom script? Basically you need to have the server generate a new page containing only the part you want to print and leave everything else out.